# WPF - Improve performances when rendering a list of objects inside a GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have issues while loading a list of 50 elements inside my RadGridView, because the rendering part takes approximately 1 second and freeze the UI for that period of time (while asking data to backend, we display a loading spinner)

So the XAML part:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items, IsAsync=True}">
```

While the Items is simply a MyCustonObservableCollection where  I defined:

```
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
```

Please note that:

- Object *A* contains like 60 properties to be filled (this shouldn't help);
- The Items collection is retrieved by making a http request to our backend. But the freeze happens after we get the data, after we add it to the custom observable collection;

My question is that I can do something to improve the performances during the rendering phase or I should just consider it as a limit for that kind of presentation. Just surprised since 50 elements is not a big number.
Searching for ideas to look at, for solving the problem.

Comment: Without knowing where the items you're trying to display are being loaded from, it's difficult to say what's causing the slowness. For example, it could be a slow database connection. Providing this context might get some more useful answers.
If there's nothing you can do about that, perhaps take a look at [this article](https://wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker/) for some information on background loading in WPF

Comment: If you're using an `ObservableCollection` you don't need to trigger Notification message manually - this will just overload the UI causing multiple triggers per entry added

Comment: How I get data is not important. I get it in an asynchronous way and during that time the UI is not blocked. After I get data I add it to my observable collection but before seeing it on my grid the UI get blocked for like 1 second.
I trigger manually the CollectionChanged event in order to avoid the multiple calls performed by the ObservableCollection for each item added (in this way the event is trigger just one time instead of 50). This was my first guess about the slowness.

Comment: As a note, IsAsync=True on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling row virtualization using.
EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True".